# How to make Kdenlive play full clip?

Tags: video, reload, kdenlive

Kdenlive, Windows version 20.12.3, won't play earlier parts of an mp4 video clip, once the clip has been played or once the playback head has been moved to later parts of the clip.  If I scan through a clip to get a sense of times, or to visualize a sequence of events prior to recording audio, then when I replay the clip, Kdenlive only shows video from the maximum location of the playback head or later; the earlier part of the clip just consists of a still image of that maximum location.

Rendering the movie creates the correct video, showing the full content of the clip, so this seems like a UI bug in editing mode.

What is the correct way to deal with this?

Comment: SO is for programming questions only, so OS support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can ask on [su] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to work around this issue is to highlight the original clip in the project bin, then select "Reload Clip" from either the popup mouse menu or from the main menu.  During the next playback, the full content of the clip will be shown. You will need to redo this each time to play the clip.

Be careful to reposition the playback head before doing this, else you'll reload the clip, then touch the playback head to position for playback, and lose the clip again.

I looked for a work-around in the settings - maybe a "reload automatically" option somewhere, but did not find one.